# Post multiple checkbox selections in comma list to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, checkbox

I'm using a script to enter data from an HTML form into a Google Sheet. Is there a way I can modify this (or add something else) so that my checkbox fields will be entered into my Google Sheet as a list, separated by commas?

So with the form below, I would want the cell for "time" in Google Sheets to list 9am,10am,11am if all boxes were checked. Right now, it only displays the value of the first box that's checked.

**Form example:**

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="time" value="9am">
<label for="time">9:00am</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="time" value="10am">
<label for="time">10:00am</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="time" value="11am">
<label for="time">11:00am</label><br>
<button type="submit">Submit times</button>
</form>
```

**The script (from https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets):**

```
<script>
  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXX/exec'
  const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to put the values of checkboxes to the Spreadsheet like `9am,10am,11am`.
- In your current situation, only value of 1st checkbox is put.
- You are using the Google Apps Script of https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets#2-create-a-google-apps-script.
- In your Spreadsheet, the header row of `timestamp` and `time` are put to the 1st row of the Spreadsheet you want to put values.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your HTML, the same name is used for the checkbox. It's `time`. In this case, you can retrieve the values by `e.parameters["time"]` at Google side.

#### Modified script:

Please modify [your Google Apps Script](https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets#2-create-a-google-apps-script) as follows.

From:

```
return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
```

To:

```
return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : (header == "time" ? e.parameters[header].join(",") : e.parameter[header]);
```

- In this case, if `time` is not existing in the header row, the values are not put. Please be careful this.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### Reference:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Unfortunately, I cannot see your current Google Apps Script and Spreadsheet. So if above modification didn't resolve your issue, I apologize. At that time, in order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the whole script? By this, I would like to check it.